# Styled Components Nested components erroring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to workout why this is erroring.
Although If I do not have CardWrapper wrapping around CardImage the image is displaying.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const CardWrapper = styled.div`
    background-color: yellow;
    border-color: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
`
const CardImage = styled.img`
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
`

const Card = props => {
    return (
      <CardWrapper>
        <CardImage src={props.data.imageUrl}/>
    </CardWrapper>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

App.js

```
<Card data={{imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/630x354', logoUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100", text: "test"}}/>
```

Error

```
./src/Components/Card/Card.js
 Error: Cannot find module '/Users/max/test/test/test/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the error and what's the expected output? You are wrapping it in a div with background yellow. What else? 

Comment: I have updated the error I am getting

Comment: remove your node modules and re-install, try again

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to install a Node.js package. In your terminal, navigate to the project's root directory and run:

```
npm install babel-preset-react-app
```